# Pattern to remove elements from ConcurrentQueue after peeking

Tags: c#, concurrency, language-agnostic, producer-consumer, concurrent-queue

I have one producer and multiple consumers. I am using `ConcurrentQueue`. I am using C# but I think my problem is language agnostics.

There can be non-unique consumers. i.e. more than one consumers can be interested in same message. So, non-unique consumers are like workers-of-one-kind.

There are unique consumers as well and since they are dealing with a queue, they assume ordering in messages.

Problem:

When a consumer `Guid-1-worker-1` peek into the queue and finds a message M1 for itself, it will dequeue it. However, because of concurrency, message M1 might have been dequeued by worker `Guid-1-worker-2`. At this time, message dequeued by `Guid-1-worker-1` is for `Guid-2`. `Guid-2` has only one worker and hence, putting the message back in queue does not help as it breaks the ordering of messages.

What I want is that if I have looked at a message, then only i should be able to dequeue it. Now, I think I have to use `lock` here. But simple `List` will work instead of `ConcurrentQueue` as well.

Is there any other data structure that provides : `Peek-Check-Dequeue` kind of concurrent semantics ?

Is there any other way to model the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Peek-Check-Dequeue` forces some kind of lock. Either you lock yourself of the data structure performs the locking (it would need to lock, then call into your code to perform the check, then unlock).

There is nothing built-in or commonly used to help with this. Just do the locking yourself.

If you have a very high frequency of such operations (millions per second) then locking overhead becomes an issue. At that point you'd need a more clever design. That would be more work and more risk for bugs.